# Bug in 2sxc Multilingual editing - anyone knows a workaround?

Tags: templates, multilingual, 2sxc, dotnetnuke

I have an annoying bug in a 2sxc Module. When I am trying to edit translated content, I get this error:

Had an error talking to the server (status 400).
Message: Bad request
Details: THe association between entity types 'ToSicEavValues' and 'ToSicEavValuesDimensions' has been sevvered but the foreign key cannot be set to null. If the dependant entity should be deleted, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.
If you are an advanced user you can learn more about what went wrong - discover how on 2sxc.org/help?tag=debug

The error appears only when editing an already stored content (I can store a translation for the first time, but have no chance to correct typos etc.)

Anyone around who knows this? Any workaround?

I must say say, I am only translating the content for this site. I did not set it up, and I did not install or configure the module. I don't have the permissions to do that on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a temporary bug in 9.5.x, should be fixed in 9.6.